# How can i pass my id from UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

i want to store my recipe id as session id when i click the button inside `UICollectionView`. Can anyone give me solution for this. i set tag value as my recipe id but i am not sure this is correct way.

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[self.mySpinner stopAnimating];

static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIButton *recipeid= (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:107];

[recipeid addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[recipeid setTag:(int)[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"RecID"]];



}


-(IBAction)aMethod:(UIButton *)sender
{

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:sender forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(@"RecipeIdsession",sender.tag)]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"recipedetail" sender:nil];
 }
```

Comment: you can go ahead , it's correct way no worries .

Comment: But when i click the button the simulator crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CGPoint` of your `Button` to get the `IndexPath` like this.

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton *)sender{
    CGPoint center= sender.center; 
    CGPoint point = [sender.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
    NSInteger recid = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"RecID"];
}
```

**Note:** Remove that `setTag` line from the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` no need to set the Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `RecID` instead of button in NSUserDefaults.

for eg:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(@"RecipeIdsession",sender.tag)]];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of "dont's" in your code. 
To point out a few,

- Ideally you should create a custom cell and have a IBOutlet for the Button in that custom cell. (I am not sure if you really require a button on a UITableCell when tableview itself has the behavior of handling selections.)
- Add Target should be never in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as this method can be called multiple times and your button target list will keep on increasing. This should be moved to your Custom Cell.
- Finally using tags should be the last option, even if you are using tags you should avoid tag numbers atleast till 20 as they might be used internally.

You should start learning form basics of using `UICollectionView`. You can refer this [link](https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/) which almost seems to implement your case but in a `UITableView`, most of the steps will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can find below code snippet for it. Hope this will help you.

// .h File

```
@interface HomeCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *recipeid;

@end
```

//    .m File

```
@implementation HomeCollectionCell
@end
```

// Your View controller .m File
    ...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HomeCollectionCell *cell = (HomeCollectionCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HomeCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.recipeid.tag = indexPath.row;
    [recipeid addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}


-(IBAction)aMethod:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    int rec_id = (int) [[array objectAtIndex:btn.tag] valueForKey:@"RecID"];
    <you code to use for rec_id>
 }
```